# Unable to get image details : Environment version Autosave_(date)T(time)Z_******** provided in request doesn't match environ

Tags: batch-processing, azure-batch, azure-machine-learning-service, azuremlsdk

On AzureML Batchendpoint, I'm recently hitting the following error:

```
Unable to get image details : Environment version Autosave_(date)T(time)Z_******** provided in request doesn't match environ.
```

when I setup the batch-endpoint with a `yml` config:

`environment: azureml:env-name:env-version`

So, AzureML creates and builds the environment with the version I specify `env-version`, which is just a number (in my case = 3).

and then for some weird reason, AzureML creates an extra environment version called `Autosave_(date)T(time)Z_********`, which is not built, but based on the previous one just created, and then it becomes the `latest` version of that environment.

In summary, AzureML instead of looking for the version that I specified as `env-name:3` it seems to be looking for `env-name:Autosave_(date)T(time)Z_********` and then throws the error message mentioned above.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the problem was that when creating an environment from a YAML specification file, one of my **conda dependencies** was `cmake`, which I needed to allow installation of another python module. The docker image is exactly the same as a previously created environment.

Removing the `cmake` dependency from the YAML file, eliminated the issue. So the workaround is to install it using a Dockerfile.

The error message was very misleading to start with, but got there in the end after understanding that AzureML reuses a cached image, based on the hash value, from the environment definition accordingly to [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/machine-learning/concept-environments#image-caching-and-reuse)

So for that reason, the automatically created `Autosave` docker image  references to that same build, which only happens once when the first job is sent.